# Data transfer increasing in firebase storage / react native app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I am fetching files from firebase storage and saving them in `AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';` in order to save data transfer and reduce the calls to firebase. When I open app and call fetch functions then everything is alright but when other project collaborators open application and fetch files it increasing data transfer. We don't understand why, we have exactly the same code.
Can anyone look at the code?

```
import React  from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {getStorage, ref, listAll, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage"
import { Video } from "expo-av";
import { ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import{useNavigation} from'@react-navigation/native';
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
import Sv from '../../languages/Sv'; 
import Eng from '../../languages/Eng'; 
import Ar from '../../languages/Ar'; 
// import icon from '../../../assets/favicon.png'




const PersonligUtveckling = () => {
  const [videoUrls, setVideoUrls] = useState([]);
  const [AudioUrls, setAudioUrls] = useState([]);
  // const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const navigation = useNavigation();


  const language = useSelector((state) => state.language); //Hämta valt språk från redux store
  const translations = language === 'Sv' ? Sv : language === 'Ar' ? Ar : Eng; // Hämtar översättningen för de olika språken


    const goBack = () => {
      navigation.goBack();
    };


   useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      FetchVideos();
      FetchAudio();
    });
      return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  const FetchVideos = async () => {
    try {
      const cachedUrls = await AsyncStorage.getItem('videoUrls');
  
      if (cachedUrls !== null) {
        console.log('Retrieved cached video URLs');
        setVideoUrls(JSON.parse(cachedUrls));
        setLoading(false);
      } else {
        const storage = getStorage();
        const listRef = ref(storage, "PersonligUtveckling/videos/");
  
        listAll(listRef)
          .then((res) =>
            Promise.all(
              res.items.map((itemRef) =>
                getDownloadURL(itemRef).then((url) => {
                  console.log("URL of video file:", url);
                  return url;
                })
              )
            )
          )
          .then((urls) => {
            setVideoUrls(urls);
            AsyncStorage.setItem('videoUrls', JSON.stringify(urls));
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          })
          .finally(() => setLoading(false));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };


  const FetchAudio = async () => {
    try {
      const cachedUrls = await AsyncStorage.getItem('audioUrls');
  
      if (cachedUrls !== null) {
        console.log('Retrieved cached audio URLs');
        setAudioUrls(JSON.parse(cachedUrls));
        setLoading(false);
      } else {
        const storage = getStorage();
        const listRef = ref(storage, "PersonligUtveckling/audio/");
  
        listAll(listRef)
          .then((res) =>
            Promise.all(
              res.items.map((itemRef) =>
                getDownloadURL(itemRef).then((url) => {
                  console.log("URL of audio file:", url);
                  return url;
                })
              )
            )
          )
          .then((urls) => {
            setAudioUrls(urls);
            AsyncStorage.setItem('audioUrls', JSON.stringify(urls));
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          })
          .finally(() => setLoading(false));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };


  
// LOGS
  const handleVideoError = (error) => {
    console.log("Video error:", error);
  };

  const handleVideoLoad = () => {
    console.log("Video loaded");
  };

  const handleAudioError = (error) => {
    console.log("Audio error:", error);
  };

  const handleAudioLoad = () => {
    console.log("Audio loaded");
  };
  
  console.log('audios: ' + AudioUrls.length);
  console.log('video: ' + videoUrls.length);

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container, styles.horizontal]}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
        { loading && videoUrls.length === 0 ? <Text>No videos found</Text> :  <ActivityIndicator size="large" />}
      </View>
    );
  }

 
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={goBack} style={styles.backButton}>
        <Icon name="chevron-left" size={30} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
       

      {!loading ?
        videoUrls.map((url, index) => (
          <Video
            key={index}
            isMuted={false}
            volume={1.0}
            source={{ uri: url }}
            style={styles.video}
            useNativeControls={true}
            resizeMode="container"
            onError={handleVideoError}
            onLoad={handleVideoLoad}
          />
        )) : <ActivityIndicator size="large" />}
       <Text>Audio</Text>

   

      {!loading ?
        AudioUrls.map((url, index) => (
          
          <Video
          
            key={index}
            isMuted={false}
            volume={1.0}
            source={{ uri: url }}
            style={styles.audio}
            useNativeControls={true}
            resizeMode="container"
            onError={handleAudioError}
            onLoad={handleAudioLoad}
            showPoster={true}
            posterSource={require('../../../assets/favicon.png')}
          />
        )) : <ActivityIndicator size="large"/>}

    </View>
  );
};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingTop: 40,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  video: {
    width: 320,
    height: 240,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  audio: {
    width: 320,
    height: 80,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  backButton: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 20,
    paddingTop: 30,
    // top: 75,
    // bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }
});

export default PersonligUtveckling;
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, looks like problem is solved. I changed approach and used `FileSystem` library instead. After updating the code it looks like that: Data transfer and database call occur only the first time. I am not sure if I should clean the cache manually or if I can let to be just like it is. Right now it seem to work properly.

```
 const FetchVideos = async () => {
    try {
      const videoDirectory = `${FileSystem.cacheDirectory}videos/`;
      const videoInfo = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(videoDirectory);
      if (!videoInfo.exists) {
        await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(videoDirectory);
      }
      const storage = getStorage();
      const listRef = ref(storage, "PersonligUtveckling/videos/");
      const res = await listAll(listRef);
      const urls = await Promise.all(
        res.items.map(async (itemRef) => {
          const url = await getDownloadURL(itemRef);
          // console.log("URL of video file:", url);
          const fileUri = `${videoDirectory}${itemRef.name}`;
          const fileInfo = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(fileUri);
          if (!fileInfo.exists) {
            await FileSystem.downloadAsync(url, fileUri);
          }
          return fileUri;
        })
      );
      setVideoUrls(urls);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const FetchAudio = async () => {
    try {
      const audioDirectory = `${FileSystem.cacheDirectory}audios/`;
      const audioInfo = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(audioDirectory);
      console.log(audioInfo);
      if (!audioInfo.exists) {
        await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(audioDirectory);
       
      }
      const storage = getStorage();
      const listRef = ref(storage, "PersonligUtveckling/audio/");
      const res = await listAll(listRef);
      const urls = await Promise.all(
        res.items.map(async (itemRef) => {
          const url = await getDownloadURL(itemRef);
          // console.log("URL of audio file:", url);
          const fileUri = `${audioDirectory}${itemRef.name}`;
          const fileInfo = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(fileUri);
          if (!fileInfo.exists) {
            await FileSystem.downloadAsync(url, fileUri);
          }
          return fileUri;
        })
      );
      setAudioUrls(urls);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```